# affine transformation on geotiff

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, geotiff-tiff, affine-transformation

I have a bunch of geotiffs stored in a PostGIS DB that i am mounting on my OpenLayers map.

[image]

They all have the geoTransform information in them. I just want to know how i can mount them on my OpenLayers map with the correct affine transformation without running a gdalwarp on all the images. Though i wouldn't mind calling gdalwarp on the fly if possible. I just don't want to store those warped images in the DB (they take up 8x more space).

**Can OpenLayers rotate my image based on the GeoTransform info in the GeoTiff? If so how?**:

[image]

This is the code i'm using to overlay my tiff:

```
var bounds = MyOrg.UI.Map.Results.Layer.features[array_index].geometry.bounds;

var options = {
    numZoomLevels: 15,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    resolutions: MyOrg.UI.Map.getMap().layers[0].resolutions,
    maxResolution: "auto",
    projection: MyOrg.UI.Map.Projections.Mercator,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
};

var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
    'test',
    'GranuleImage.ashx?granuleID=' + MyOrg.UI.Map.Results.Data.arrGranules[array_index].id + '&thumb=0',
    bounds,
    bounds.getSize(),
    options
);

MyOrg.UI.Map.getMap().addLayer(graphic);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Openlayers cannot warp your images.  OpenLayers reprojection/transform support is for vectors only.

For a raster solution, you will need to do the processing on the server side.  You will have to determine if performance is enough of an issue that you decide to pre-process the imagery.  If you want to do it on the fly, you could use MapServer or another WMS server.  If you pre-process them, you could use MapServer or another WMS server, or you could build up a tile cache.

Raster processing is fairly expensive.  You essentially have to determine whether 'disk is cheap' or 'time is cheap'.

Comment: +1: Are you saying i can point geoserver to my table of rasters and then be able to overlay them properly? Will WMS do the transform for me?

Comment: nevermind, answered my own question> NO. WMS will not do it directly from PostGIS i need the physical file.

Comment: @capdragon:  according to this page, MapServer can serve up rasters (WKT Raster) from a PostGIS db.  YMMV, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Could you please paste the link you're referring to in and edit or comment box. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for failing to post the link.  http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/RT_FAQ.html#id2816828  and http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/156-PostGIS-Raster-its-on-10-things-you-can-do-NOW-with-raster.html